# How to display User liked "Term"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I want to show to all users who like "Term", how do I do it?

And this is what I did.

likes_controller.rb

```
 def index
    @likes = Like.all
 end
```

index.html.erb (like)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">STT</th>
      <th scope="col">UserName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @likes.each do |like| %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= @like.id %></th>
      <td></strong><%= @like.user.username %></strong>></td>
      <tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

like.rb

```
id, term_id, user_id
```

routes

```
resources :terms do
    resources :likes
end
```

term

```
belong_to :user
has_many :likes
```

user :

```
has_many :likes
has_many :terms
```

like :

```
belong_to :user
belong_to :term
```

I'm not sure if I have provided enough documents, if not, please leave me a comment

Comment: What does your user model look like?

Comment: class Like < ApplicationRecord                                                   
      belongs_to :term                                                               
      belongs_to :user                                                               
      scope :publics, -> (user_id, term_id) { where(user_id: user_id, term_id: term_id) }
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be precise with this without you updating the question to show the relationships setup in the three models, but you could do something like:

```
#term.rb
has_many :users, through: :likes
```

That'll give you access to `term.users` directly, returning all those that have liked the term.

You could then load the term in your controller (be sure to eager load the users):

```
def index
  @term = Term.find(params[:id]).includes(:users)
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<% @term.users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row"><%= user.like_id %></td>
    <td><strong><%= user.username %></strong>></td>
  <tr>
<% end %>
```

Please note I've switched to use two `td` tags in the loop - the `th` tag should be used for the header row.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions :)

Comment: But I think his params will be coming through as `term_id` from his routes file (despite my earlier attempt :D )

Comment: Thanks @Mark - this is something of pseudocode answer as the question's missing a bit of vital info, though you're likely right there. Hope my comment didn't come across has harsh rather than helpful by the way - it was meant to be the latter, though not always the simplest to get across via text :)

Comment: The joys of trying your best not to sound rude online :D All fair points and well made :)

Comment: Thanks @vinduongtang - really helpful. Looks like the above (perhaps with some slight tweaks - check you've got the right params in `Term.find(params[:id])`) should work. Give it a pop and let me know how you get on or if you've any question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# likes_controller.rb

def index
  @term = Term.find(params[:id]
  @likes = @term.likes
end
```

```
## likes/index.html.erb

<% @likes.each do |like| %>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= @like.id %></th>
    <td></strong><%= @like.user.username %></strong>></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Couldn't find Term without an ID

Comment: This has a nasty N+1 issue in the loop @Mark.

Comment: @vinduongtang How are your params coming through? Please put a binding.pry point in your index action of the controller and post the output of `params`

Comment: It must be :
```<% @likes.each do |like| %>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= like.id %></th>
    <td></strong><%= like.user.username %></strong>></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>```
anyway thanks you so much :)